# Convert Typed Arrays at runtime

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I want to create a Collection based on type declared in 'convertToType' Or 'myElementType'. It has to be a typed collection (which I need for further use).  I don't want an Untyped collection.

What I tried so far is

```
Dim field As PropertyInfo
'_attribute is the name of the property
field = doc.GetType().GetProperty(_attribute)
Dim convertToType As Type = field.PropertyType
Dim myElementType As Type = convertToType.GetElementType()
```

I've tried:

```
Dim myList as List(Of convertToType)
Dim myList as List(Of convertToType.GetType())
```

Different attempts with Arrays.  But it's not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Obviously some extra information is in order. My bad :)
The method looks like this (i made it somewhat smaller and simplied):

_attribute: Name of the property
Me.Value: Is a property inherited from the superclass (refers to a selected value by the user) is an Array[Object]

```
Public Overridable Overloads Sub GetData(ByRef doc As ClassA)

    Dim fieldOperator As PropertyInfo
    Dim value() As String
    fieldOperator = doc.GetType().GetProperty("operator_" & _attribute)
    fieldOperator.SetValue(doc, Me.[Operator], Nothing)
    If Me.[Operator] <> Proxy.EasyExploreServices.SearchOperator.NoSearch Then
        Dim field As PropertyInfo

        field = doc.GetType().GetProperty(_attribute)
        Dim convertToType As Type = field.PropertyType
        Dim myElementType As Type = convertToType.GetElementType()

        // DO SOME CONVERSION
        Dim arrListObject As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
        For Each myObj As Object In Me.Value
            If (myElementType Is Nothing) Then
                arrListObject.Add(Convert.ChangeType(myObj, convertToType))
            Else
                arrListObject.Add(Convert.ChangeType(myObj, myElementType))
            End If
        Next
        // END CONVERSION

        field.SetValue(doc, // My New Collection //, Nothing)

    End If
End Sub
```

Problems further on in the code (if no coversion is made). Types other then Strings throw exception because for example Object[] cannot be converted to Int[] (for example)

Comment: Show more code. If we can see how this is used, we may be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: What may work is to define a CLass as (Of T) where you define T based on `GetType(convertToType)` and inside is a `List(of T)` to store the data you are collecting.  Hard to tell without more code.  whether it is a compiler error would be helpful to know too.

Comment: Another thing ArrayLists aren't typed.  It won't matter what type you add it will be returned untyped as object.  A point of reference, ArrayList is not Array.  There are significant differences.

Comment: Tinstaafl: yeah Arraylist did give me the same problems.  For the time being, we provided a temporary fix for Integers. Right now only integers or strings are expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to get the `Type` object for the generic `List(Of T)` class.  You can do that like this:

```
Dim genericType As Type = GetType(List(Of ))
```

Notice that the type argument is omitted.  Next, you need to get the `Type` object for a `List(Of T)` where `T` is whatever type is described by `convertToType`.  To do that, you can use the `MakeGenericType` method, like this:

```
Dim specificType As Type = genericType.MakeGenericType({GetType(convertToType)})
```

Now that you have the `Type` object, you can create an instance of it.  For instance:

```
Dim myInstance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(specificType)
```

It's hard to say where doing this kind of thing would be very useful.  Typically, the value of using a generic list is that you get the safety of the added type-checking at compile time.  When you are creating it through reflection, and then using it `As Object` in a late-bound manner, it would seem like you are losing most of it's value.

Comment: Somehow at runtime i get the error: convertToType is undefined.  We are currently investigating an alternative way to implement the function. Thnx for the hint though. Your given code will be usefull in other applications.